# dos command in visual studio installer project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer

i want to execute a command say "net start "servicename" from within installer, i can't use custom actions any ideas?

Comment: Why you can't use custom actions?

Comment: Executing the "net start servicename" command would be a custom action...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the command into a batch file, install the file and execute it. Doesn't give you much information about how the command went, though.